# Hover effect to cover another field

Tags: html-table, hover, background-image

The table has two rows and one column. Each field has a background image (50px height) and another image for the hover effect, which is the first field 100px and in secound 50px.

My question has to do with this effect. When you hover on the first field to show an image of 100ps, which covers the second field without moving the table?

I tried this but it only expands height of the first field without cover second field.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table {border: none;}
     .one:hover {background-image: url('1.jpg'); height: 100px; }
     .two:hover { background-image: url('2.jpg');}
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <tr style="background: url(td-one.jpg);" width="200" height="50" >
       <td  class = "one">Firstname</td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background: url(td-two.jpg);" width="200" height="50">
       <td class = "two" >Lastname</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<td>` will never break out of the `<tr>` structure (row height), so it will never cover the cell below it. You will need to add a `<div>` inside your cells for each, `.one` and `.two`.

Then changing the height of the `<div>` and playing around with `float:left` on this `<div>` might render what you want.